# Jumping animation playing only once should all the times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public void JumpingStuff()
{
    if (_grounded == true)
    {
        playerAS.clip = playerjump2;
        playerAS.Play();
        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
        m_Jump = true;

        //here allow to end the animation if some time was passed
        if (!hasJumped && m_Animator.GetBool("Jumping"))
        {
            m_Animator.SetBool("Jumping", false);
        }
    }
    //(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps > 0)
    // PC
    if (extraJumps > 0)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        extraJumps--;

        if (m_Jump == true)
            m_Animator.SetBool("Jumping", true);
        playerAS.clip = playerjump;
        playerAS.Play();
        //Debug.Log("playing jumping animation");

        //here your player has began the jump
        if (!hasJumped)
        {
            hasJumped = true;
            StartCoroutine("WaitBitAfterJump");

            //Play sound when he jump
            //playerAS.PlayOneShot(playerjump);
        }
    }
    //(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps == 0 && _grounded == true)
    //PC
    else if (extraJumps == 0 && _grounded == true)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        m_Animator.SetBool("Jumping", false);
        Debug.Log("I am Jumping");
    }
}
```

please help me fix my code (i know is messy it is my first time)

i was changing my code from PC > mobile and i get these errors :

jump only once should be twice 
and play animation only for first time

Comment: So the `errors` are no errors but rather unexpected behavior, right?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing "else" in line

```
if (extraJumps > 0)
```

So when you enter that JumpingStuff and the first condition is met

```
if (_grounded == true)
```

it sets your extraJumps value and the second condition is also met, so both jumps are executed at same time.

after stripping off unnecessary code it looks like this:

```
if( grounded == true ){
    PlayJumpAnimation();
    extraJumps = 1;
}

if(extraJumps > 0){
    PlayJumpAnimation();
    extraJumps--;
}
```

so basically when grounded == true, extraJumps is set to 1 and extraJumps > 0 is also true so both PlayJumpAnimation(); are executed at same time without that else, it should look more like this:

```
if( grounded == true ){
    PlayJumpAnimation();
    extraJumps = 1;
}
else if(extraJumps > 0){
    PlayJumpAnimation();
    extraJumps--;
}
```